# Golang: запись вида map[string]interface{}{}

Tags: golang, map

Разбирая открытый код проекта, встретил вот такую запись

`args := map[string]interface{}{}`

Не могу понять что это за карта и какого вида значения в ней должны хранится.

Весь контекст в котором используется запись в качестве request передается route вида controller/action в качестве Params как я понял json:

```
func (connect *Connect) Request(request string, params string) (interface{}, error) {
    req, err := connect.factory.NewRequest(Host)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    args := map[string]interface{}{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(params), &args)

    resp, err := req.Do(request, args)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    result, err := resp.GetMethodResult()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return result, nil
}
```

Прошу приведите пример.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

map[string]interface{} - это карта, где ключ string, а значение удовлетворяет типу interface{}

interface{} - это пустой интерфейс, ему удовлетворяет любой объект (аналог void* из C)

а последние "{}" это инициализация карты без значений (типа как `map[int]int{1:2, 3:4}` )

можно переписать в виде

```
args := make(map[string]interface{})
```

или более развернуто

```
type any interface{}
var args map[string]any
args = make(map[string]any,0)
// или просто args = make(map[string]any)
```

Comment: Спасибо, исчерпывающе... как раз смущали вторые скобки, не знал что так можно инициализировать.

Answer (score 1):

`map[string]interface{}` - это лишь указание типа, что ваша переменная типа ключ - строковая, и переменная типа `interface{}`. 
когда вы объявляете переменную такого типа:

```go
var a map[string]interface{}
a["test"] = 1
\\ panic: assignment to entry in nil map
```

, то будет ошибка. Нужно инициализировать пустую мапу:

```go
var a map[string]interface{}
a = map[string]interface{}{}
a["test"] = 1
```

, после чего, с ней можно работать.